# Find length of trough

Tags: matlab

I have a bunch of graphs like this in MATLAB and I have the corresponding data (~25000 points per graph).
[image: example plot]

I want to find out the length of the longest time during which Data is 0 (highlighted portion in the above figure). Problem is there are other shorter periods of time during which the data is 0, and there can be tiny peaks within the period (as can be seen at 1.4 x10^4) mark on x-axis.

I am looking for a way to programmatically find this out in MATLAB. The length of this period as well as other troughs in the data varies a lot but generally the one I am looking for is the longest.

Comment: "A long series of zeros" could be defined as places where regional sum is minimal (or close enough to 0). You can get regional sum by `convolve`, find the lowest and then expand to both sides with a threshold to accept tiny peaks.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `convolve` over `movsum`?

Comment: The expected output would be the length of time during which Data was zero. Or if we are treating it as array of zeros then the length of this array basically.

Comment: @TWhelan `movsum` actually seems better. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox and the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox, here is a very short solution.

Borrowing from 2D mathematical morphology, we just see the sequence of zeroes/not zeroes as a binary image. The area of each component is the length of a contiguous sequence.

```
% Indexes of 0-valued elements: 
% you might want to adjust it for real/noisy data (e.g. data < 1e-10)
idx_zero = (data == 0);
% Assign a consecutive number to each 0-valued consecutive region
constants = bwlabel(idx_zero);
% Count the area of each region
counts = tabulate(constants);
% Maximum region size, and location (the first row refers to non-zero entries):
[max_run_length, max_label] = max(counts(2:end, 2))
max_run_length

% Bonus: the region indexes are
find(constants == max_label)
```

(There is probably a faster way without using any toolbox.)

Comment: This does work for most of my datasets. However I had to set the threshold equal to mean of data since there were some peaks which were high but they should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient way to do it, but easy to follow:

```
data_length  = length(data);
max_length   = 0;

trough_length = 0;

for ii = 1:data_length

    if data(ii<threshold) %whatever your noise threshold is
        trough_length = trough_length+1;
    else
        if trough_length >= max_length
            max_length    = trough_length;
            trough_end    = ii-1;
        end

        trough_length=0; 
    end     
end
```